# How to calculate inductive and capacitive reactance?

Tags: power, capacitive, inductive, reactance

I am studying a project that calculate reactance power. I can measure apparent power, real power and power factor. Therefore I can calculate total reactance power. But I don't know whether it is inductive reactance or capacitive reactance.
[This is my circuit](http://openenergymonitor.org/emon/buildingblocks/how-to-build-an-arduino-energy-monitor)

How can I describe values of inductive and capacitive reactance?
Thanks

Comment: Please show a proper circuit and not a cartoon of what you have built.

Answer (score 1):

P = S*cos(phi)

Q = S*sin(phi)
cos(phi)...power factor
sin(phi)... positive value means inductive load, negative value means capacitive load

Comment: Adding to Marko's answer. Remember CIVIL.
In a Capacitive system the current (I) leads the Voltage.
In an Inductive system The Voltage leads the current (L).
You are reading phase to determine the power factor so polarity of the power facter will determine inductive or capacitive.

Comment: I need that phi angle. How can I calculate it?

Comment: I can read instatenous voltage and current values but how can I understand whether voltage is leading or lagging.

Comment: You should ask the author of that library, he would know where to insert a flag whether is cap or ind.